# The document “queue.h” could not be saved

Tags: objective-c, xcode, queue

I am working/learning on my project (Objective C, Xcode). At that time I was working with:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()
```

Now, when I want to run or debug my program. I see this window during each run:

[image: window]

How to undo all changes in this file and make this window no longer show.

Comment: Did you modified a Framework file which is named `queue.h`? Like a "internal file", and you can't really modify it...

Comment: I have a similar situation and even I cannot close Xcode, I have Xcode 11.3..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar issue but for queue in C++. I caused mine by accidentally applying the fix suggestion "Fix in 'queue' " offered by the compiler—I assume that that is how yours happened too. I force quit X Code, thus losing any unsaved changes, and then reopened the app. That seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Accept my answer? This isn't my post.

Comment: I have this issue on Xcode 11.3 / 11.2 but could not resolve yet, any idea ?

Comment: @RakshithaMurangaRodrigo I saw from your comment on the main post that you couldn't even close Xcode. Are you unable even to force quit it? When I had the problem, normal quitting didn't work but force quitting did.